# Document personalization in Pimcore?

Tags: target, pimcore, personalization, targeting

Document personalization doesn't work in pimcore. I click the button "Edit Content for Target Groups", choose the Target group, Overwrite the content, Save and Publish page, reload page and the orginal content is disappear. It looks like all content is deleted.

How to fix this ???

Comment: Which version of Pimcore You're using?
What do you mean by "original content is disappear"? Are the overwritten editables empty or they show overwritten content?

Comment: I solve this problem. I have $page->save() in view. When I had removed it, it began working.